# Continuous Form - Open Form for Selected Record

Tags: ms-access, selecteditem, recordset, continuous-forms

I have a continuous form in Access.  The detail is set up with a button in the detail for every record.  The button has on-click code to launch a pop-up form with detail about that record.  I have record selectors showing, and those show that when I click a command button, the record selector for the current record is selected.  I put a stop in my code when the form is opened and the criteria shows the current selected criteria correctly.  when the form opens, it opens to the first record in the record set from the main form, instead of the current selected record on the main form.

I have been searching all over, figuring this has to have been answered, but I can't seem to find a solution that will work right for me.

Below is my code.  If anyone can assist, I would really appreciate it.

```
Private Sub cmdOpenDetails_Click()
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

stDocName = "frmAssetDetail"

With rst
    Me.txtAssetTag.SetFocus
    stLinkCriteria = Me.txtAssetTag.Value
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, acNormal, "Forms![frmAssetDetail].AssetTag = ' " & stLinkCriteria & " ' "
    Forms!frmAssets.Visible = False
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this:

The command button opens a form with the ID parameter, as in:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmAddresseeEdit", , , , , , Me.ID
```

The form (in this case "frmAddresseeEdit") has as its Record source `qrySelectedAddressee`

This query has the fields required by the form and its criterion is

```
id = [Forms]![frmAddresseeEdit].[OpenArgs]
```

Comment: One problem I am having is when do I close the main form?  The situation is that I have multiple forms and a user can open any form from any other form.  They can go back and forth.  So each time I need to open the requested form, passing the criteria each time. I was originally just making the form that I was leaving visible = false, but that makes it hard to use an isloaded evaluator to determine what form I need to get my criteria from.  Does all this make sense?

Comment: Is it necessary to "open any form from any other form"? The forms where I've used the above solution are all set `Modal = True` so they can only be dealt with one at a time - just to avoid the situation you describe.  A possible alternative is to set a `visible=false` field in the form just opened with the id and use that field as the selection criterion.  I've not tried this, so your mileage may vary!.

Comment: Actually I took your suggestion all the way through and was able to clean up all transitions to all my forms.  Now most all buttons to open forms look like this  `Private Sub cmdOpenDetails_Click()
Dim stDocName As String  
stDocName = "frmAssetDetail"  
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, acNormal, , , , , Me.AssetTag  
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmAssets", acSaveYes  
End Sub`  
and most all form open code looks like this:  
`With Me.Form
        .Filter = "Left([AssetTag],6) = " & Me.OpenArgs
        .FilterOn = True
    End With`  
it is so much cleaner!